# Python higher-order sequence assignment?

Tags: python, syntax, programming-languages

Is there a way to group names together in python, to repeatedly assign to them *en masse*?

While we can do:

```
a,b,c = (1,2,3)
```

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
names = a,b,c

*names = (3,2,1) # this syntax doesn't work

a,b,c == (3,2,1) #=> True
```

Is there a built-in syntax for this? If not, I assume it would be possible with an object that overloads its assignment operator. In that case, is there an existing implementation, and would this concept have any unexpected failure modes?

The point is not to use the names as data, but rather to be able to use the actual names as variables that each refer to their own individual item, and to be able to use the list as a list, and to avoid code like:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3

sequence = (a,b,c)
```

Comment: This seems to be another instance of mixing data with variable names.

Comment: See http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html

Comment: @SvenMarnach seems to be a lot of that about these days.

Comment: Python has such an elegant namespace organization, study it a little before pulling a stunt like this. http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/scopes.html

Comment: @PauloScardine: I'm familiar with python namespace rules. I can't create a module inside a function, so I'm not sure what you're suggesting. Perhaps an answer would be a good way for you to elucidate.

Comment: @delnan: This use case it not related to anything in the link you provide.

Comment: @Marcin My comment was meant to supplement Sven Marnach's. And yes, what you're trying to do sounds an awful lot like mixing up data and variables.

Comment: @Marcin: of course it's related. You think you want variables named `a`, `b`, and `c` for some reason. You're wrong.

Comment: @Wooble: So, do you write all of your programmes with just one big list of values, and use only integers instead of variables?

Comment: @Marcin The idea that `names` contains/refers to the locals `a`, `b` and `c`. Normally, assignment of one variable does not affect the others.

Comment: @delnan: It is true that "normally, assignment of one variable does not affect the others", but I fail to see how that constitutes mixing data and variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This?

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> names = namedtuple( 'names', ['a','b','c'] )

>>> thing= names(3,2,1)
>>> thing.a
3
>>> thing.b
2
>>> thing.c
1
```

Answer (score 2):

You should go one level up in your data abstraction.  You are not trying to access the entries by their individual names -- you rather use `names` to denote the whole collection of values, so a simple list might be what you want.

If you want both, a name for the collection *and* names for the individual items, then a dictionary might be the way to go:

```
names = "a b c".split()
d = dict(zip(names, (1, 2, 3)))
d.update(zip(names, (3, 2, 1)))
```

If you need something like this repeatedly, you might want to define a class with the names as attributes:

```
class X(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.update(a, b, c)
    def update(self, a, b, c)
        self.a, self.b, self.c = a, b, c

x = X(1, 2, 3)
x.update(3, 2, 1)
print x.a, x.b. x.c
```

This reflects that you want to block `a`, `b` and `c` to some common structure, but keep the option to access them individually by name.

Comment: I'm not trying to use the names as data; I actually want to use them as individual variables.

Comment: @Marcin: But trying to put the names inside some `names` meta-name *is* treating them as data.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a helpful way to define "mixing data with variable names" if one is not performing operations on the names beyond the usual operations of reading and setting.

Comment: Anyway, namedtuples are probably the best solution where `name = (a,b,c) = (1,2,3)` isn't the solution.

Comment: @Marcin: What else would you ever do with a variable, apart from reading and  setting?  I think the difference to the usual case of data/variable name mix-up is that in your case the names seem to be at least fixed at compilation time.

Comment: @Marcin: I removed the `namedtuple` version again because I decided I don't like it.

Comment: You could, for example, concatenate them, to retrieve another object by name. I hope you're not eating your lunch right now ;).

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [**`dict`**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

```
>>> d = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
>>> d.update({"a": 8})
>>> print(d)
{"a": 8, "c": 3, "b": 2}
```

Comment: I don't really see how this matches the question.

Comment: HexTree: the first sentence just screams dictionary: `Is there a way to group names together in python, to repeatedly assign to them en masse?`.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that you still need to repeat the names every time you want to reassign, which is exactly what the OP wnated to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I've realised that "exotic" syntax is probably unnecessary. Instead the following achieves what I wanted: (1) to avoid repeating the names and (2) to capture them as a sequence:

```
sequence = (a,b,c) = (1,2,3)
```

Of course, this won't allow:

```
*names = (3,2,1) # this syntax doesn't work

a,b,c == (3,2,1) #=> True
```

So, it won't facilitate repeated assignment to the same group of names without writing out those names repeatedly (except in a loop).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you shouldn't do this, since it's potentially unsafe, but you can [use the `exec` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec)

```
>>> names = "a, b, c"
>>> tup = 1,2,3
>>> exec names + "=" + repr(tup)
>>> a, b, c
(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: I don't see how this is an advance over just using sequence assignment.

Comment: It is not at all an advance! It's a terrible idea. But it allows you to do something closer to what it seemed like you wanted....

Answer (score 0):

Python has such an elegant namespace system:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class GenericContainer(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._names = []
        self._names.extend(args)
        self.set(**kwargs)
    def set(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for i, value in enumerate(args):
            self.__dict__[self._names[i]] = value
        for name, value in kwargs.items():
            if name not in self._names:
                self._names.append(name)
            self.__dict__[name] = value
    def zip(self, names, values):
        self.set(**dict(zip(names, values)))

def main():
    x = GenericContainer('a', 'b', 'c')
    x.set(1, 2, 3, d=4)
    x.a = 10
    print (x.a, x.b, x.c, x.d,)
    y = GenericContainer(a=1, b=2, c=3)
    y.set(3, 2, 1)
    print (y.a, y.b, y.c,)
    y.set(**dict(zip(('a', 'b', 'c'), (1, 2, 3))))
    print (y.a, y.b, y.c,)
    names = 'x', 'y', 'z'
    y.zip(names, (4, 5, 6))
    print (y.x, y.y, y.z,)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Each instance of GenericContainer is an isolated namespace. IMHO it is better than messing with the local namespace even if you are programming under a pure procedural paradigm.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure whether this is what you want...

```
>>> a,b,c = (1,2,3)
>>> names = (a,b,c)
>>> names
(1, 2, 3)
>>> (a,b,c) == names
True
>>> (a,b,c) == (1,2,3)
True
```